# Need help with some real estate math in java

Tags: java, android, math

Need help with some real estate math in java this blows up each time

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // This app total real estate fees for a client selling a house

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);

         //  Sample data for priceText 360000
        final EditText priceText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        // Sample data for rateText .04
        final EditText rateText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText02);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
 {
 public void onClick(View v) 
 {
 Toast.makeText(jsclosingcost.this, "Doing Closing Cost Breakdown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                //  Sample data for priceText 360000
  float fPrice=Float.parseFloat(priceText.getText().toString() + "");
                 // Sample data for rateText .04
  float fRate=Float.parseFloat(rateText.getText().toString() + "");

  float fRealEsate = fPrice * fRate;
  Toast.makeText(jsclosingcost.this, "Real Estate Brokerage Fee: " + fRealEsate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
 });


    }
```

Comment: "this blows up each time" is far from a precise description. What happens? Why are you concatenating a string with an empty string?

Comment: Perhaps, use android:digits or android:numeric?

Comment: it looks like that won't even compile... and you never show() the toast for:"Doing Closing Cost Breakdown".  is jsclosingcost your Activity?  That isn't a very good name for a top-level java class... can you post more code, and your error message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like others have said, "This blows up every time" doesn't give us a lot to go on. That said, I tossed this into a test project and found that it doesn't compile - you're missing a semicolon at the end of this line:

```
Toast.makeText(jsclosingcost.this, "Doing Closing Cost Breakdown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
```

By adding a semicolon to that line, I was able to compile this and run it without issue.

A few things of note, however...

---

You don't need to append an empty string to your strings here:

```
float fPrice=Float.parseFloat(priceText.getText().toString() + "");
float fRate=Float.parseFloat(rateText.getText().toString() + "");
```

Appending an empty string in this way is an old trick to ensure things are cast as String objects, but by calling toString on the objects, you've already guaranteed that they're String objects.

---

I don't know what's considered "best practice", but the first parameter to the Toast.makeText method is a "Context" object. I'd feel more comfortable getting the Context from the view object passed to your onClick handler, like this:

```
Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Doing Closing Cost Breakdown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

---

You don't have any sorts of checks on your edit fields in case someone fails to fill them in. For example, if someone fails to enter a value into EditText01 and they press your button, you're going to end up with a NullPointerException right here:

```
float fPrice=Float.parseFloat(priceText.getText().toString() + "");
```

You could easily guard against this by doing something like this, instead:

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
   Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Doing Closing Cost Breakdown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

   float fPrice, fRate;

   try
   {
      fPrice = Float.parseFloat(priceText.getText().toString());
      fRate = Float.parseFloat(rateText.getText().toString());

      float fRealEsate = fPrice * fRate;
      Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Real Estate Brokerage Fee: " 
         + fRealEsate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
   {
      Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), 
         "Please enter numeric values for Price and Rate.", 
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   } 
}
```

---

Please name your buttons and edittext boxes something better than Button01 and EditText02. Using good names will make your life (and everyone else's lives) easier.