# How do I change TextView Value inside Java Code?

Tags: java, android, textview

I am working on a android program. A user clicks on a button I do some math and I would like to change the values that I have on my view in some TextView objects.  Can someone please tell me how to do it in my code?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I presume that this question is a continuation of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762688/need-help-with-some-real-estate-math-in-java).

What are you trying to do? Do you really want to dynamically change the text in your TextView objects when the user clicks a button? You can certainly do that, if you have a reason, but, if the text is static, it is usually set in the main.xml file, like this:

```
<TextView  
android:id="@+id/rate"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/rate"
/>
```

The string "@string/rate" refers to an entry in your strings.xml file that looks like this:

```
<string name="rate">Rate</string>
```

If you really want to change this text later, you can do so by using Nikolay's example - you'd get a reference to the TextView by utilizing the id defined for it within main.xml, like this:

```
final TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rate);
textViewToChange.setText(
    "The new text that I'd like to display now that the user has pushed a button.");
```

Answer (score 17):

First we need to find a `Button`:

```
Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
```

After that, you must implement `View.OnClickListener` and there you should find the `TextView` and execute the method `setText`:

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
        mTextView.setText("Some Text");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, add a textView in the XML file

```
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/rate_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/what_U_want_to_display_in_first_time"
    />
```

then add a button in xml file with id btn_change_textView and write this two line of code in `onCreate()` method of activity

```
Button btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id. btn_change_textView);
TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rate_id);
```

then use `clickListener()` on button object like this

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      
        textView.setText("write here what u want to display after button click in string");
    }
});
```